# Instant app CLEARTEXT communication not supported: []

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-instant-apps

I tried to do `HttpUrlConnection`, but got **Exception**:

```
    java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication not supported: []
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
    at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
    at com.xfzj.instantappdemo2.feature.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:84)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here's my code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("responseCode",""+connection.getResponseCode());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }).start();
```

If I ran and installed the app, it succeeded.

or I replaced `http://www.google.com` with `https://www.google.com`, it also ran successfully in instant app.

Does instant app only support Https?

Answer (score 4):

That's right. HTTP connections are unsupported: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/policy.html#network_traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below line into the manifest file

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Can anyone verify this works with InstantApps? Does not seem so on my end...